# Kohana Auth не работает login

Tags: php, kohana-3

Зарегистрировал пользователя, проверил в phpMyAdmin, он существует.
При попытке логина выдает ошибку, хотел бы узнать, что именно не так.
Функция входа:

```
public function logUser($array)
    {
                $username = $array['username'];
                $password = $array['password'];
                $remember = isset($array['remember']) && $array['remember'];
                if (Auth::instance()->login($username, $password, $remember))
                {       
                    echo 'Hello, '.$username;
                }else
                {
                    echo 'Error';
                }
    }
```

Вызов этой функции:

```
$post = $_POST;
$loguser = Model::factory('Log')->logUser($post);
```

Config-файл:

```
'driver'       => 'File',
'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
'hash_key'     => 'fhsjgbsefhbsaiuhfbsjkdhgbdijhrbg',
'lifetime'     => 1209600,
'session_type' => Session::$default,
'session_key'  => 'auth_user',
```

Comment: Смотрите что за ошибка и делайте выводы.

Comment: Гениально, как я сам не додумался...
Ошибка выводится через echo, самого Exception нет, потому и залил сюда вопрос

Comment: Что вы как маленький? Через `var_dump` код что ли ни разу не отлаживали? Пора начинать

Comment: Да, ни разу не отлаживал и даже не знаю, что это, было бы неплохо разъяснить, вместо того, чтобы писать "Разбирайтесь с проблемой сами"

Comment: Вам нужно посмотреть что за ошибку отдает Kohana, желательно преложить код ошибки суда

> application/logs/YYYY/MM/DD.php

Скорей всего у вас нету прав на создание auth_file в директории проекта.